# Modularising Terraform IaC across microservice environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, microservices, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to refactor my IaC Terraform set up to repeat less code and be quicker to make changes. I am working on a serverless microservice application, and so, for example i am running a few instances of aws-ecs-autoscaling and aws-ecs. I have develop and production environments, and within each one a modules folder where each microservice module is defined. Please see image for mock folder structure.

[image]

As you can see there are many repeated folders. In the main.tf of the dev and prod environments each module is called and vars assigned.

EG:

**ecs-autoscaling-microservice-A main.tf**

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target" {
  max_capacity = 2
  min_capacity = 1
  resource_id = "service/${var.ecs_cluster.name}/${var.ecs_service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace = "ecs"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_memory" {
  name               = "dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_memory"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization"
    }
    target_value       = 80
  }
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_cpu" {
  name = "dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_cpu"
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace = aws_appautoscaling_target.dev_ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }
    target_value = 60
  }
}
```

**DEVELOP main.tf**

```
module "ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A" {
  source      = "./modules/ecs-autoscaling-microservice-A"
  ecs_cluster = module.ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A.ecs_cluster_A
  ecs_service = module.ecs_autoscaling_microservice_A.ecs_service_A
}
```

My question is what is the best way to go about removing all modules. SO that instead of having an ecs module for each microservice for both prod and dev environments, I can just have 1 module for ecs, that can be re used for any microservice in any environment. See Image for required folder structure. Is this possible or am i wasting my time? I was thinking of using some kind of for_each where each microservice is defined before hand with its owned mapped variables. But would like some guidance please. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You would have to parameterize your modules. You could also use tf [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#multi-account-aws-architecture) for dev and prod environments.

Comment: you can create module of module. and reuse your custom module. Make sure you follow DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the excellent series of blog posts on Terraform by Yevgeniy Brikman which cleared my understanding of Terraform:

https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-terraform-b3d32832baca

This exact question seems to be touched on in this one: https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d